# How to properly get connections from pgPool-II with JDBC in the case of a multi-user application?

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, junit, pgpool

My company plans to use **pgPool-II** in order to benefit of its *"Fail Over"*, *"Load Balancing"* (and eventually *"Replication"*) features.

We consider here that we have a **J2EE Tomcat** web application hosted by a servers cluster where **Jakarta Tomcat Connector (JK)** or similar service is used to do the link between clients and these **Tomcat** servers (*load balancing*). Also, we consider that we have a cluster of **PostgreSQL 9.3** databases where **pgPool-II** is used to do the link between the **Tomcat** servers cluster and the databases cluster. Our application is a multi-user application where each user is associated to a different role (in terms of databases of course).

I learned that **pgPool-II** use the same protocol than **postgreSQL** so to connect to the pool we just need to connect to it as we usually connect to a database, right?

In [this mail copy](http://www.sraoss.jp/pipermail/pgpool-general/2014-January/002489.html), I saw that it's useless to have 2 pool layers, so no need to use **JDBC Tomcat pool** in addition to **pgPool-II**. Either we delegate the pool task to **JDBC Tomcat pool**, either we delegate it to **pgPool-II**, right?

So my final questions are :

- How to properly get connections from **pgPool-II** with **JDBC** in that case, must I simply demand a new connection to **pgPool-II** every time a user need to execute a **SQL** request? Does not affect performance?
- Which part should take charge of pool task in order to obtain the best performance? **JDBC Tomcat**, **pgPool-II** or another service like **pgBouncer**? What is the best approach?

Thanks in advance!

**PS** : If some points aren't clear, please tell me and I'll edit my post.

Comment: I made some integration tests and benchmarks with JUnit. Starting from a Tomcat server, JDBC Tomcat pool seems to be a little faster than PgBouncer, probably because it is embedded in the Tomcat application so in that case there are no tier services between Tomcat server and database...